A basic set theory exercise
I am learning the basic axioms of set theory. I have done this brief proof exercise and would like to know if it makes sense or if it is more or less correct, what inaccuracies it has, or how to improve it:
Prove that $$\mathcal{P}\emptyset = \{\emptyset\}$$
Starting from the definition of the power set, $$\mathcal{P} X \equiv \{ u \mid u \subset X \}$$, and the definition $$\{ X \} \equiv \{ u \mid u = X \}$$
We simply substitute the variables from the general definitions with those specific to the problem at hand to obtain:
$$X = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow u = \emptyset$$.
(Note: I add this to make it clearer: $$u = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow u \subset \emptyset$$ [by the principle of reflection], and since $$\emptyset \subset \emptyset$$
Then: $$\mathcal{P} \emptyset \equiv \{ {\emptyset} \mid \emptyset \subset \emptyset \}$$
Conclusion: $$\mathcal{P} \emptyset = \{\emptyset\}$$

Use $x$ for $x$ instead of $$x$$ for $$x.$$ Also, please make your titles more informative.

Actually, the "to make it clearer" thing is precisely what you need to show. (The preceding statement involving $X$ and $u$ makes no sense.)
